# What do I need to do that appendChild and addEventListener is going to work?

Tags: css, reactjs, dom, addeventlistener, appendchild

I can see the issue here. Stuff is going to fetch before it's still there in the order of code execution, but I don't know how to fix that at all.

I want to grab some infos from my firebase firestore database and put it in the dom in a way I can show it of nicely.

The other thing is, css file isn't working cause of the same issue. When I setAttribute to it it's already initialized and of course, it wouldn't show up at all (for example: border: 50% to make the pic round).

What do I miss to learn?

```
import React from "react";
import firebase from "./firebase";
import "./artists-styles.css";

const db = firebase.firestore();

const form = document.querySelector("#add-artist-avatar");

function renderArtists(doc) {
      
  const artistsAvatar = document.querySelector(".content");

  let image = document.createElement("img");

  image.setAttribute("src", doc.data().avatar);

  artistsAvatar.appendChild(image);
}

// getting data

db.collection("artists")
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.docs);
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data());
      renderArtists(doc);
    });
  });

// saving data

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  db.collection("artists").add({
    avatar: form.avatar.value,
  });
  form.name.value = "";
});

const Artists = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Cloud Cafe</h1>
      <form id="add-artist-avatar">
        <input type="text" name="avatar" placeholder="Artists Avatar Link" />
        <button>Add Avatar</button>
      </form>
      <div className="content"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Artists;
```

Comment: You should avoid direct DOM manipulations when using React. I would suggest retrieving the artists when you component mounts into the DOM (it can be done via hooks or with componentDidMount lifecycle method). Also check the documentation on how to work with forms in React (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need something like this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import firebase from "./firebase";
import "./artists-styles.css";

const db = firebase.firestore();

const Artists = () => {
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("artists")
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.docs);
        setDocs(snapshot.docs);
      });
  }, []);
  
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection("artists").add({
      avatar: inputValue
    });
  };
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Cloud Cafe</h1>
      <form id="add-artist-avatar" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <input
            type="text"
            name="avatar"
            placeholder="Artists Avatar Link"
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Add Avatar</button>
      </form>
      <div className="content">
        {docs.map(doc => (
          <img src={doc.data().avatar}/>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Artists;
```

Comment: I can see whats happening here, but it always says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined".

Comment: @minternational I've edited my answer. Still, I'm suggesting checking the docs on the React forms. This should explain a lot.